# determine the roots of $X^{2}-1$ in $\left(\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}\right)[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have no clue what to do here. Any tips/hints?

I already got 1 and -1=35

Because $(-a)^{2}-1=(a)^{2}-1$ i only need to check the first 18 digits. And because $(2k)^2 - 36 \cdot q \neq 1$ the even digits will fail.

I now don't know how to proceed, do i need to check all remaining digits by filling them in or can i exlude a lot more?

Comment: can i assume you know what does it mean for a polynomial to be irreducible?

Comment: @praphulla Kousik yes i know that, but that information is on the next chapter. So i should solve this problem without having any knowledge of irreducible polynomials....

Comment: I am not asking information about irreducible polynomials... i am asking "definition" of irreducible polynomials.... have you checked by just squaring each element in $\{1,2.\dots 36\}$ and go mod 36???

Comment: Chinese Remainder Theorem?! Well 36 is such a small number that you could just try all the (coprime to 36) residue classess by hand.

Comment: Do you know what a root is? And do you really mean "the roots in $(\Bbb Z/36\Bbb Z)[X]$" or do you actually mean "the roots in $\Bbb Z/36\Bbb Z$"?

Comment: @rschwieb i know what a root is, its when $X^{2}-1=0$ in our modular group. And yes i mean the roots of $\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}[X]$. :)